# natbib: temporary citation for missing references?

Tags: natbib

Is there a way I can specify a placeholder text for citations in which bibliographies are missing? For instance, I would imagine the syntax might look something like `\citep[Author, Year]{AuthorYear}`. I tried using `\defcitealias` but I guess that does not work if the bibliography entry is missing.

Comment: Would setting up a dummy entry of type `@misc`, with a key named `dummy`, a year field of `9999`, and every other field taking a value of `dummy`, be a way to go? You could issue citation commands such as `\citet{dummy}` as placeholders until the real entries are set up.

Comment: Oh I see, so it would have to be done in the .bib file. But I know the first authors and year to use in the citations (so I can be more clear to myself than `dummy`), I just need to go retrieve the entries. ;)

Comment: Use `\citetemp{Author, Year}` defining it as `\newcommand{\citetemp}[1]{(#1)}`. You can then search for `\citetemp` and fix the key.

Comment: @egreg Make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a temporary command in your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\citetemp}[1]{(#1)}
```

and use `\citetemp{Author, Year}` in the document body, with whatever you like, say

```
\citetemp{Gödel, 1931}
```

It will be easy to use your editor's search facility for finding `\citetemp` and fix it with the key.